# Does the argument for the irrationality of 2 only work for prime numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I mean the argument that uses the fundamental theorem of arithmetic. Doesn't this theorem assume that p, if we are proving √p is irrational, is prime? However I see that proofs online of any other number that's not a perfect square use the same logic for proof (e.g √6).

Comment: It works for all squarefree numbers.

Comment: It works for all nonsquare numbers

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to $m$ be a prime to do the argument on $\sqrt{m}$, just to not be a perfect square, as in that case it is rational.

As we know every natural has a prime factorization so you can take $p$ the smallest prime that divides $m$ and its power is not even in the factorization, and do kind of the same argumentation.

- the argumentation

let's suppose $\sqrt{m} = \frac{a}{b}$ with $a$ and $b$ naturals and coprimes, then we have that $ m = \frac{a^2}{b^2} \iff mb^2 =a^2$ then as $p \mid m \implies p \mid mb^2 = a^2 \implies p\mid a$ , lets call $a = a_1p$ then we have that $mb^2 = a_1^2p^2$ in here we have two options $p^2 \mid m$ or not if it doesn´t we conclude the same way. but if it does you have that at least $p^3\mid m$ because the power of $p$ in $m$ is not even, and dividing by $p^2$ you arrive to the beginning but with a $m_1 = \frac{m}{p^2}$ so this algorithm will end in a finite number of cases, then you conclude that $a_n$ and $b$ are not coprime and that is a contradiction.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).